# how to create JSON webservice, can Anyone refer any tutorial for this

Tags: asp.net

I Cant Able to find out correct soltion . Our client is Android and Iphone. now i need to create a webservice for these two client. I dont know even a single step  about this. please any one refer any tutorial website or guide to me.I am using .asmx form.And i use C#

Answer (score 1):

At a high level, its very simple. Instead of returning HTML code in response to an HTTP GET or POST, you will now return a JSON string. The real question is how do you create a JSON string from the object that you want to send.

There are several libraries that can take an object and return a JSON string. In python you can use

```
return simplejson.dumps(<<object name>>)
```

in php,

```
echo json_encode(<<object name>>);
```

Which language are you using?

Comment: I am using asp.net with C#.. i am creating .asmx web service. let me know how to deploy my webservice.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend to do a REST service.

I've accomplished that by using an HTTP Handler (.ashx) and NewntonSoft.Json (just returning the literal string and changing the content type to "application/json".

If you want to be more fancy WCF supports json as well but I found the handler approach to work very well. Also the Json serializer that Newton uses worked better for me than the Microsoft one.

You can get his Json library using Nuget as well as downloading from the site.

Some resources:
http://www.dotnetperls.com/ashx and

http://james.newtonking.com/pages/json-net.aspx